# How to create a conditional task in Taskfile?

Tags: automation, devops, pipeline, taskfile

I have three tasks created with [TASKFILE](https://taskfile.dev/), `main-task` and its two preconditions(or deps) e.g `A` and `B`. I need the `main-task` to run task `A`, if task `A` works fine and did the job then ignore the second task `B`, otherwise fallback to task `B` and execute it  (that's why I added `ignore_error: true`). How to put this logic inside `main-task` using taskfile syntax? thanks

Example:

```yaml
---
version: 3

tasks:
  A:
    cmds:
      - cmd: exit 1
        ignore_error: true
  
  B:
    cmds:
      - exit 1

  main-task:
    deps: # Run A only, But if it fails then Run B
    cmds:
      - task: # or here: Run A only, But if it fails then Run B
```

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `makefile` so you should probably remove that tag.

Comment: @MadScientist they are alternatives, most of us migrating makefiles to taskfiles and vice versa all the time.

Comment: Sure, but _this question_ doesn't have anything to do with makefiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to run a task only if another one failed. You can run it only if succeeded by calling it after the previous one, or always by using [`defer`](https://taskfile.dev/usage/#doing-task-cleanup-with-defer).

Comment: you are the main contributor, so I am gonna mark your answer as accepted for now. thanks a lot

Comment: @JehadNasser In case you need to ask more questions, the Discord server has more people answering questions, so it's more likely you'll get a response and sooner.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use template engine and some kind of `if` statement like this:

`- cmd: sh -c '{{if eq .CLI_ARGS "my_flag"}}echo "executing additional task" && <shell task command>{{end}}'`

https://taskfile.dev/usage/#gos-template-engine

https://go-task.github.io/slim-sprig/